# Why SQLite data base values are not retrieving?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I tried storing some data to a `c#, XAML` project. When I add data in get stored to database. But when I tried to retrieve them back it doesn't happens. What is the reason.

**The code to store values**
values are passed through parameters . They are user inputs.

```
var DBPath = Database.DB_PATH;
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
{
      db.CreateTable<User>();
      db.RunInTransaction(() =>
      {
          db.Insert(new User()
          {
              userName = uName,
              password = pass,
              email = mail,
              country = countRy,
           });
      });
}

MessageBox.Show("Details Added");
```

**Retrieve values**

```
var _user = db.Query<User>("select * from User").FirstOrDefault();
db.RunInTransaction(() =>
{
      if (getUserName.Text == (_user.userName))
      {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + getUserName.Text);
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Map.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
      }
      else
      {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Credentials");
      }});
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors. It just don't happen at the button press.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see exactly where it fails? You're not giving us much to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You have to commit the changes after inserting the record.
call `db.commit()` after inserting record.

Answer (score 1):

When exiting transaction mode, you need to either `Commit` or `Rollback`, to apply or revert your changes.

Make sure you are calling `db.Commit()` on your insertion before retrieving your values.